# What would cause streaking in graphics LCD display?

Tags: lcd, glcd, graphics

[image: Streaks on LCD]

I am using a 128x64 graphic LCD module that uses either [NJU6676](https://www.tvielectronics.com/documents/NJU6676.pdf) or [ST7565P](https://www.crystalfontz.com/controllers/Sitronix/ST7565P/444/) similar to [this Zettler module](https://www.azdisplays.com/PDF/aqm1264pa.pdf). I am getting vertical streaks as pictured. They appear to be most pronounced when the topmost pixel in the column is dark.

When I use a [different module](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/909/Kyocera_07272016_F-51553GNBJ-LW-AGN-1384817.pdf), I get no streaks. However, when I use the demo board sent by Zettler, there are no streaks with the Zettler board, but there is slight streaking and blotchy contrast with the Kyocera board.

I have varied the V5 ("electronic volume") level with minimal changes to the streaking, and I have varied the C2 caps (see schematic below) from 0.1 µF to 1 µF (there is disagreement on the values and range of these caps on various internet sites). The refresh rate has been slowed to once per 2 seconds per the manufacturer's advice. The streaks are still present.

In my current hardware, the topology of the circuit is basically like so, but with the common C2 node being tied to +3.3 V:
[image: Datasheet diagram]

Unfortunately I am not set up to change the firmware right now, so I'm a bit hamstrung, which is why I'm exploring hardware fixes first.

Has anyone seen this and know what causes it?

Comment: possibly caused by the contrast setting

Comment: @jsotola, As I adjust the contrast, the contrast indeed changes, but the streaks are still visible.

Comment: Apparently the letter "t" in the top row. If you leave the top (1 pixel) row blank, does it go away? This is suggesting something like crosstalk from data to supply (or contrast as js says ... does that need decoupling?)